Custom document class always pick the default logo even if I change to other logos
I want to create a custom class with an option to change logo. But the default logo is always selected even if I change to other logos.
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2024/12/01 v 1.00 class for fun]
\def\@logo{defaultlogo}
\DeclareOption{logo}{\def\@logo{#1}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[twoside,12pt]{article}


\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\insertlogo}{%
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{\@logo} 
  \end{figure}
}
\endinput

\documentclass[logo=otherlogo]{myclass}
\begin{document}
\insertlogo
\end{document}

What is wrong?

Are you sure you want your logo to be in a float?

@cfr: only for testing.

You need to define the options as keys, for example like this:
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2024/12/01 v 1.00 class for fun]
\def\@logo{defaultlogo}
\DeclareKeys[myclass]{
    logo.code = {\def\@logo{#1}}
}
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler{
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessKeyOptions\relax
\LoadClass[twoside,12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\insertlogo}{%
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{\@logo} 
  \end{figure}
}
\endinput

